# Get number of days for a month from given month and year EXCEL

Tags: excel, days

Let say cell `A1` has year
cell `B1` has month

In cell `C1` I want the number of days of month given in cell `B1` in the year `A1`

For example: If `A1=2016`, `B1=2`, now `C1` should return the number of days in February 2016.

**What I have tried**

In `C1`
`=DAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(B1)+1,))`

But this does not work

I'd be grateful for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
=DATE(A1,B1+1,1)-DATE(A1,B1,1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Or you may try this...

=DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(A1,B1,1),0))

Answer (score 0):

Less transparent but this will also work

`=42-DAY(DATE(A1,B1,42))`

format as general

Answer (score -1):

Excel have a lot of functions that are unknown for most users. `EOMONTH` is the function you need in your case. It returns the last date of the month for a given date.
Consider you have a cell `A1` with `TODAY` function and you want the last date of the month. In B1 you put:

```
=EOMONTH("A1",0)
```

So in B1 will show `30/04/2017` (for those whose date format is `dd/mm/yyyy`).